# How to pass image to python script in EEL

Tags: javascript, python, eel

I'm making a desktop app with python + eel.

So, JS draws on a canvas. When done, it should pass the image to the python side which should save it to disk.

```
    ==> Javascript

var the_canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();
```

Now, the_canvas should be saved to the local disc.
I shouldn't use dialogue and press enter to save. Saving should go without me, on its own.

So far no idea how to do it, please help.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with this sentence : " I shouldn't use dialogue and press enter to save. Saving should go without me, on its own." ? That user should'nt be prompted the browser file download dialog ?

Comment: Exactly. The user should not be prompted. Actually, I started to mess with EEL exactly for that. Because I know that plain JS doesn't allow saving without prompt.
I need the image to be sent to the python side and python then should save.

Comment: Start a grab server on the python side, then post the image to the server and close it. Or base64 encode the image and pass it to the python.